# Angular JS Root scope after form submit

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-scope

I am a rookie in angular js. In my application, I want to save an object into $rootScope and do a post request which does not contain the object in rootScope.

In new page which has just opened, I want to use that object from rootScope but as I have understood, after a full redirection , rootscope loses its state or I am doing something wrong:)

In general, without a full refresh, is there a way to store variables into rootscope or should I have to pass it with each request from one to another?

THX

PS: I do not using ng-view and looking for something without ng-view...

Comment: Angularjs is SinglePageApplication FrameWork, so you cannot pass values to another page unless you store it in a cookie or local storage of a browser.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I get it. After a full redirection , all the scopes are recreated by app itself. So there can not be any previous data in new scopes. In order to do that, the ng-app should not be refreshed and ng-view should be used, or webstore,cookie etc should be used.

Thx fellas

Answer (score 1):

You may have to use the browser's local stroage, if that is an option.

Answer (score 0):

if I well understand what you are looking for, I think you can do it with a Factory.....

```
    app.factory('myService', function() {
 var savedData = {}
 function set(data) {
   savedData = data;
 }
 function get() {
  return savedData;
 }

 return {
  set: set,
  get: get
 }

}
```

Comment: nop, this will not work because the page is not partially refreshing. It is a full redirection and all the scopes of angular will be created again.